# While Combinig Bootstrap and JQM

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

For some reasons I have to use JQM and Bootstrap in my mobile application. 
But the problem is that there is a conflict between them. The proble is that the footer will appear fine WITHOUT bootstrap link but once its is added, only half of the footer will be seen. How do we solve this issue ? Is there any way to say html page to use a certain css conditionally ?
Thanks in advance.
CODE:

```
<!--HEADER-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.min.css"/>

<!-- STUFFS-->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
<p align="center">&copy; Mobile App</p>
</div> <!-- FOOTER -->
```

Comment: can you check the console for any error?

Comment: I will see if I can figure out that way. Thanks